# Computing Pipeline logistic regression predict_proba in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, pca, logistic-regression, predict

I have a dataframe with 3 features and 3 classes that I split into X_train, Y_train, X_test, and Y_test and then run Sklearn's Pipeline with PCA, StandardScaler and finally Logistic Regression. I want to be able to calculate the probabilities directly from the LR weights and the raw data without using predict_proba but don't know how because I'm not sure exactly how pipeline pipes X_test through PCA and StandardScaler into logistic regression. Is this realistic without being able to use PCA's and StandardScaler's fit method?

So far, I have:

```
pca = PCA(whiten=True)
scaler = StandardScaler()
logistic = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = True, class_weight = 'balanced', solver = sag, n_jobs = -1, C = 1.0, max_iter = 200)

pipe = Pipeline(steps = [ ('pca', pca), ('scaler', scaler), ('logistic', logistic) ]

pipe.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predict_probs = pipe.predict_proba(X_test)

coefficents = pipe.steps[2][1].coef_ (3 by 30)
intercepts = pipe.steps[2][1].intercept_ (1 by 3)
```

Comment: The X_train and X_test must go through the exact same transformation for the predicted results to be correct. What is the problem in using `pipe.predict_proba(X_test)`?

Comment: If you are worried that in the `pipe`, if you send `X_test`, `pca` and `scaler` will be fit again then dont worry. Only `transform` will be called in them and `predict_probas` on `logistic`.

Comment: The problem with pipe.predict_proba(X_test) is that the new test data will be fed in manually in real time so I just need a way to do the transform, I guess. when PCA and scaler transform X_test, it's just using the fit parameters from X_train, right?

Comment: Yes. A pipeline behaves like any other estimator. You `fit` on training data and only call `predict` or `transform` on test data. When you call `predict_proba` on a pipeline, all estimators excluding the last one will only call `transform` and then pass the data further. The last one will call `predict_proba`

Answer (score 0):

This is also the question I don't figure out, thanks for Kumar's answer.
I regarded pipeline will lead to new transform for **x_test**, but when I tried to run  **Pipeline** composed of **StandardScalar** and **LogisticRegression**, and to run my own defined function using **StandardScalar** and **LogisticRegression**, I found that **Pipeline** actually use the **transform** fitted by **x_train**. So don't worry about using pipeline, it's really a convenient and useful tool for machine learning!